# C# program exception

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

An exception occured. Exception is specified cast is not valid

```
int s = (int)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: we can *guess* that you're wondering why you got this error, and how to get rid of it... but it would be nice if you put in a little extra effort and actually phrased it as a question instead of leaving us to guess.

Comment: Are you trying to get the index or the value stored in the comboBox? Please specify, so that a meaningful answer can be given.

Comment: An exception occurred. Not a real question `throw new Exception("Not a real question");`

Comment: @David Hedlund: `throw new DavidHedlundDoesNotUnderstandException()`

Comment: `throw new ArgumentOutOfCoffeeException("leppie")` =) I'll understand the question when OP states one. Until then, I can have a guess just as anybody else, but I'd prefer not having to (`return MarksArgument;`)

Comment: @David Hedlund: Guessing is not hard when you only have 1 choice. So many fail to understand that it seems...  :|

Answer (score 4):

It means the value in the combobox's items is not an `int`.

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct, but useless. The OP still doesn't know what he should do. I'd prefer those voted-down answers, which is more help to a beginner.

Comment: @Danny: well this question is completely bloated with tangent discussions by now, so I'm not sure that OP will be able to distill anything of value out of it, but ultimately, the accept tick is the only marker of what OP found most helpful, so I'm sure that this will sort itself out. Having said that, I do agree that the assumptions made in the voted-down answers are not senseless ones. It's always good practice to point out when you're making an assumption, though: "Hey, if what you want to do is *A* then you could do, this, if you really meant *B* then ..."

Answer (score 2):

Check SelectedIndex > -1 or SelectedItem != null

Comment: And as @leppie says it does assume that all values in the comboBox are ints

Answer (score 1):

try

```
int s = int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

you can not convert any object to an `int` by just casting. If you have a `string` you need to use [`int.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) to convert a `string` to an `int`.

If you insert your own objects as Items in the combobox you can cast `comboBox1.SelectedItem` to your type instead.

`ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()` only returns the content if you have inserted string objects in the combobox, a more reliable way is to check the [`ComboBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) property instead. This will also save you from some `null` checking.

Comment: `SelectedItem.ToString()` will yield something like `System.Net.UI.Controls.ComboBoxItem.OrWhatever` which cannot be parsed to an int. This won't work at all.

Comment: @David: If the content is strings it will work. I'l edit my post to recommend comboBox1.Text instead.

Comment: @David Hedlund: What are you talking about? There is no combobox in ASP.NET.

Comment: @leppie: hence the `OrWhatever`. I didn't bother to look at exactly where the class belonged, because that wasn't my point at all.

Comment: @Albin: yeah, with `.Text` I don't have a problem with your solution at all =)

Comment: @David Hedlund: It's a DropDownList in ASP.NET. So we are dealing with WinForms.

Comment: @leppie: yes, I gathered. That doesn't change the fact that `ComboBox.Text` is the more reliable and semantically correct way of getting the text of the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value that is displayed in the combo box, maybe you should try :

```
int s = (int)comboBox.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: That all depends on how you databind the ValueMember. But if left default and empty, it should work. But if selected item fails, this will also fail.

Comment: Yes. But are we supposed to guess this kind of details...?

Answer (score 1):

Example usage on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx?ppud=4)

But really, you need to provide more details in the question :)

Total guess but a common thing to do may be to store a database id in a comboboxes value property and the database item text in the text property. If this is what you are doing then you can use the below syntax if you know for certain that the value of the combobox is always castable to an int.

```
int i = (int)ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

or if your not sure it's always an int you can...

```
try
{
int i = int.Parse(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
catch
{
//handle the non int situation here
}
```

or

```
int i;
bool result = int.TryParse(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out i);

            if (result)
            {
                //you can use the variable i now
            }
            else
            {
                //The parse failed so handle a non int situation here
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Convert.ToInt32(combo.Items[combo.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

```
int s = comboBox.SelectedIndex
```

Comment: @leppie I wouldn't be much surprised if sheena meant to get the index of the selected item, not the value of the selected item itself. So this suggestion makes sense, even if it is an assumption (which you're almost forced to make, seeing as how little information the question contains).

Comment: @Rob: You are making an assumption, I am not. What is wrong with getting an `int` out of the selected item? Nothing!

Comment: If the OP wanted to get the int out of SelectedItem, he would most likely be aware he needs to do some kind of conversion. In my eyes it is pretty obvious he wants the index of the selected item.

Comment: @leppie of course I'm making an assumption, but I've explained why.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to cast a ComboBox Item to an int.

Try

```
int s = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
```

if you want the index of the item.

Comment: Why -1? I don't think @Brissles is wrong, except a flaw: `s = (int) comboBox1.SelectedIndex`, no `(int)` is needed because `SelectedIndex` is an `int`.

Comment: @Danny: the -1 is probably because somebody's crusading against the assumption that `SelectedIndex` is what OP was trying to get at all. I don't have a problem with the assumption myself. Given the complete lack of an actual question, I guess we're all at liberty to fill in the blanks here.

Comment: @David: Exactly. Some OPs don't describe their questions well, it's not because they are lazy or they don't want to. The reason is probably they are not familiar with the issue. So I think a good answer should point out the error, and giving a possible solution is much more important.